# Trie Data Structure Space complexity

Tags: data-structures, trie

I am wondering how to calculate the space complexity of the trie structure.
As I have been calculating that if the depth(length of word) is N and Pattern Size K(for small alphabets 26) and number of words: W
As per my understanding, it should be: K^N

Whereas many places it is written that is WxKxN.

Could you please elaborate on which is correct and How?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, it should be O(K^N)

Let's assume that word length is 1, then a single array of size k would be sufficient.

**Ex : 'b' (position = 1) k =  [null, pointer to another array of size k, null, null, null, ........]**

Let's assume that the word length is 2, then we need to have an array of size k for each of the characters which are at the first position in the word

**Ex: 'ba'**

**level 1 ('b') : [null, pointer to an array (lets call it Z) in level 2, null, null, null, ......]**

**level 2: Z (Second character  'a') : [pointer to another array of size k, null, null, .......]**

Let's say we are inserting 'bc' then we are going to have another array of size k for 'c' at position 3 (Assuming you are inserting 'a' at 0, then 'b' at 1 and so on)

So at each level 0, we have an array of size k (***size at level 0: K***), at level 2 we have k array's of size k (***size at level 1: k^2***), at level 3 we have a k^2 number of array's of size k (***size at level 3: k^3***), and so on.

So the space complexity will be **k** + **k^2** + **k^3** + ..... **k^N** (N is word length). This is the worst-case time complexity.